# Input and save answer

Tags: arrays, input

So I want to ask the user to input some details like name etc, and then add them to an ArrayList. If the user enters blank spaces a message will be shown and the user will be asked to enter again.

```
System.out.println("Name: ");

String name = input.nextLine();

while(name.contains(" ")){

System.out("Names can't be empty");

System.out.println("Name: ");

name = input.nextLine();

}

Person newP = new Person(name);

persons.add(newP);
```

Code works fine if the user enters some characters. However if he doesn't and enters the while loop, what gets added is just the blank spaces.

What can I do to make sure it adds the input inside the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a while loop to loop throught the input command until the variable `name` is anything other than "" (nothing):

```
System.out.println("Name: ");

String name = input.nextLine();

while(name.contains("")){

System.out("Names can't be empty");

System.out.println("Name: ");

name = input.nextLine();

}

Person newP = new Person(name);

persons.add(newP);
```

Your problem was that you had the while so that it didn't want `"  "` not `""` this means that when you just hit enter the value was nothing not a space.. so it would continue.

I also made it in python because I thought you were using python at first so if for whatever reason you want it, here it is:

```
print("Names can't be empty")
name= ""
while name == "":
    name = input("Name: ")
print (name)
```

Good luck!

Comment: @Ilja You are very welcome. If my answer solved your problem please hit that check mark next to my answer, and consider pressing the up arrow if you liked my answer! Thanks, and I'm glad my answer helped you!